# Making repetitive CountDownTimer with Different Times

Tags: java, android, for-loop, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to learn coding. So I decided to make a little project but i stuck.

I am trying to make a CountDownTimer. I have 3 different times. For example first one is 10 sec, second one 5 sec and the third one is 7 sec. So I wanna make an app that start the count from 10 sec and when it finish it start the count from second timer and then third one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private Button mResetButton;
    private Button mStopButton;

    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private TextView mTextViewCounter;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private int countme = 0 ;
    private int [] array = new int[3];


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mStartButton = findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    mStopButton = findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
    mResetButton = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    mTextViewCounter = findViewById(R.id.text_s);

    array[0]=10000;
    array[1]=5000;
    array[2]=70000;


    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

                mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(array[i], 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         mTextViewCountDown.setText(""+ millisUntilFinished/1000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        countme++;
                        if(countme / 3 == 3){
                            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                        }else{
                            start();
                        } } }.start(); 
                         } 
                         } 
                        }); } }
```

I don't think for loop is right for my problem. It does not increase variable i once, it increase in every ontick i guess. As a beginner, I couldn't figure out what should I do.

Comment: If you trying to start the countdowntimer one after another with a single button click why don't you use 10 + 5 + 7 (ie 22 secs) and condition in `onTick`

Comment: maybe you can use `Thread.sleep(array[i]);` to wait the loop as long as the value in array

Comment: Because I don't want to user see total time in screen. Times for each person. There are task todo in limited time. First guy start and when his time is over, it switches to the 2. guy and then 3. guy. So every one has to see their limited time in screen, not the total time.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need for loop try something like this:

```
private void startCountDowntimer(long millis, int count) {
        count ++;
        int finalCount = count;
        new CountDownTimer(millis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTextViewCountDown.setText(""+ millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (finalCount == 1) {
                    startCountDowntimer(5000, 1);
                } else if (finalCount == 2) {
                    startCountDowntimer(7000, 2);
                } else {
                    //all finished
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

and on the button click:

```
mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCountDowntimer(10000, 0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: For some reason it doesnt count accurately. Only first time is correct. Second one is goes like 5 3 2 1 0 and third one is 7 5 4 2 1 0